# A lot of columns in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS don't exists in the actual table

Tags: google-bigquery, information-schema

I need to create a dynamic query in Google Bigquery, and for that I'm using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.
the problem I'm facing that a lot of the columns in the COLUMNS table doesn't exist in the original table, what could be the reason for this problem?

I tried to compare between the columns that really exist in the table and other columns but they look the same and there's absolutely no difference between them

```
#standard SQL
SELECT
  CONCAT('select ',columns,',count(*) n from `',table_catalog,'.',table_schema,'.',table_name,'` group by ',columns)
FROM (
  SELECT
    STRING_AGG(column_name,', ') columns,
    table_name,
    table_catalog,
    table_schema
  FROM
    `MY_PROJECT.MY_DATASET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` a
  WHERE
    a.table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
    AND ordinal_position IS NOT NULL
    AND column_name <> 'EXCLUDED_COLUMN'
  GROUP BY
    table_name,
    table_schema,
    table_catalog);
```

The resulted query contains a lot of columns that are not in the actual table and running the resulted query keeps giving me the following error:

Unrecognized name {column_name} at {position}

Comment: any examples of such "extra" columns?

Comment: after rechecking, this issue happens with views, if the column is dropped from original table , the column still appear in the schema of the view, so I created another view with the same query and the schema was correct without any "extra" columns

Answer (score 0):

This could be a side effect of `Time Travel`.  `DROP` and re`CREATE` the table, or just wait 7 days if that is an option for you.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69291989/7359502