# BigQuery Drop Table Column - DDL Bug

Tags: google-bigquery, ddl

After removing a column from a table by:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS MyColumn
```

In BigQuery UI I Can see that the column was deleted successfully & I can't query the specific column but when I query DDL I can see that the column still exists in the scheme:

```
SELECT DDL FROM MyDataSet.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE DDL LIKE '%MyTable%'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a nasty, undocumented side effect of Bigquery's [Time Travel](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel).  Time Travel makes it unsafe to use `ALTER TABLE` statements in bigquery.

**Demonstration of problem:**

```
create table apu.time_travel_problem 
( id int64
, name string
);

select column_name, data_type 
FROM apu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'time_travel_problem';
```

| column_name | data_type |
| --- | --- |
| id | INT64 |
| name | STRING |

This is all normal so far, but after an `ALTER TABLE` everything goes odd:

```
alter table apu.time_travel_problem drop column name;

select column_name, data_type 
FROM apu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'time_travel_problem';
```

| column_name | data_type |
| --- | --- |
| id | INT64 |
| name | STRING |

The column we just dropped is still there!

Now try this:

```
alter table apu.time_travel_problem add column name string;
```

```
Column `name` was recently deleted in the table `time_travel_problem`. Deleted column name is reserved for up to the time travel duration, use a different column name instead.
```

**Solution:**

Do not use `ALTER TABLE` in bigquery.  Instead `DROP` and re`CREATE` using a temporary table.

This is a [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/) template which I use:

```
/* {{TABLE}} */

ALTER TABLE {{DATASET}}.{{TABLE}} RENAME TO {{TABLE}}_migration;

ALTER TABLE {{DATASET}}.{{TABLE}}_migration
SET OPTIONS (expiration_timestamp = timestamp_add(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR))l


CREATE TABLE {{DATASET}}.{{TABLE}}
(
{{COLUMN_DDL}}
);

INSERT INTO {{DATASET}}.{{TABLE}}
(
{{COLUMN_LIST}}
)
SELECT
{{COLUMN_LIST}}
FROM {{DATASET}}.{{TABLE}}_migration;
```

Comment: problem with this is the cost. You will pay for those queries. Yet it is a solution but not free as should be and it is with alter table

Comment: My issue is that even if after 7 days, the time travel feature still stops me from adding a new column....

Comment: @Stan you can entirely bypass the time travel by dropping the table.  That's what my answer is about.
7 days if the default setting, it's possible to specify a [different option on a dataset, see `max_time_travel_hours`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#bq)

Comment: @StevenEnsslen will it cost too much to create such bug temp table and insert?

Comment: @StevenEnsslen I am pretty sure we are using the default 7 days. Could it be whenever query fails against this column, the 7 days will get refreshed?

Comment: @Stan I don't know if the 7 days gets restarted.  My budget is large enough / my data is small enough that I've not needed to investigate that closely.  Sorry that's not helpful.

Comment: Renaming the column before droping it let's me create it again. `ALTER TABLE testing.test2 RENAME COLUMN ColumnName TO NewUselessName;` then `ALTER TABLE testing.test2 DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS NewUselessName;`

Comment: @DanielOlson I think that you should propose this as a new answer.  I believe that `RENAME COLUMN` didn't work when I answered this.  I've tried this recently and I am using it for pure renames, where the data type isn't also changing.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you can rename the column before using `DROP`.

```sql
-- rename the column to a useless name (I use uuid within python)
ALTER TABLE testing.test2 RENAME COLUMN OriginalName TO NewUselessName;

-- then you can delete the column as expected
ALTER TABLE testing.test2 DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS NewUselessName;

-- then you can work as normal. example of adding a column:
-- ALTER TABLE testing.test2 ADD COLUMN OriginalName STRING;
```

I believe [the accepted answer by @Steven Ensslen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69291989/19907524) gives a good explanation on why this is happening.